# Regular expression only one character and 7 numbers

Tags: c#, regex

i want regex match only one char in any position of word and 7 numbers

```
match example:
1111111q
2222222q
111e1111
11e11111
```

i do this pattern but not working in all patterns:

```
[A-Za-z][0-9]{7}
```

Comment: Are all seven digits identical?

Comment: just for clarification, i believe you mean one `letter` not `char`

Comment: can you explain  more

Comment: YES @Jonesy one letter and 7 numbers

Comment: ok but in  which order

Comment: any order @K.B like examples above

Comment: Are you trying to extract this from a larger string or are you just checking to see if a string matches a pattern?

Comment: take a look  at my answer for the right regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only come up with a "brute force" regex method:

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, 
    @"\b
    (?:[a-z]\d{7}|
    \d[a-z]\d{6}|
    \d{2}[a-z]\d{5}|
    \d{3}[a-z]\d{4}|
    \d{4}[a-z]\d{3}|
    \d{5}[a-z]\d{2}|
    \d{6}[a-z]\d{1}|
    \d{7}[a-z])
    \b", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Note the word boundary anchors, which you should remove if this pattern is part of a longer string.

Also note the IgnoreCase option, which you can remove if all letters will be lower case.

**Edit**:  See @stema Answer -- much more concise regex

Answer (score 7):

Regular expressions match patterns. In your case, it would seem that the letter can be at any point in your string, which would mean that you would have a multitude of patterns which would need to be taken into consideration.

I think that for this case, you should not use regular expressions for simplicity's sake. I would recommend you take a look at the [`Char.isDigit(Char c)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx) and [`Char.isLetter(Char c)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx) methods and use counters to see that the string is in the format you are after.

Comment: He's asking for 7 different patterns, which isn't an unreasonable amount. I generated the required regex strings with a short script and simply linked them up using alternations.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis: I wasn't saying that what he is asking for is unreasonable, just that given this particular problem regular expressions aren't the easiest, most readable way.

Comment: unbelievable the OP want a regex not hard code and you  get the upvote  :( hmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: @K.B: Since the OP also mentioned the usage of `C#`, the community provided a different (more readable) way in which the same result can be achieved.

Comment: ok so you are participating in creating more stupid incapable programmers that's can't live without stackoverlflow :P

Comment: npinti, I think he just did :-)

@K.B I disagree that teaching programmers to explore alternative solutions that lead to more readable code increases their stupidity and incapability.

Comment: @CompuChip: I agree with you. Just because someone wants to use a particular approach when the same problem can be solved in an easier way using something else.

Comment: OK bu at least you should provide both  solutions  with advantages and disadvantages that will  be a great answer but not as you know the only alternative you make this as the only OP choice

Comment: @K.B. Other people have provided other solutions through regular expressions. If I also did that I would be repeating what other have said.

Answer (score 4):

there are readily available methods in C# for checking the conditions you want. I would use Regex if there is no parser or simple c# solution.

I would do like below

```
var str = "1111111u";
var isValid =  str.Length ==8 && 
                   str.Where(char.IsDigit).Count() ==7 && 
                   str.Where(char.IsLetter).Count() ==1;
```

Comment: `x=>char.IsDigit(x)` can be replaced with simply `char.isDigit`.  And same for `IsLetter`.  Just throwing that out there.  Method groups are cool.

Comment: Upvoted this solution - I think regexes are unnecessarily complicating here because of the requirement (I think, based on the examples) that the digits on both sides of the letter should be the same.

Comment: unbelievable the OP want a regex not hard code and you  get the upvote  :( hmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: @K.B in my experience people are often looking for a solution to a particular problem, and they ask for a specific direction because they _think_ it will be the proper tool to use. Often they are not right and it turns out there is an easier solution. If OP has a reason to absolutely _have_ to use regular expressions, I will be happy to upvote the ridiculously complicated (something with named groups and/or lookaheads, is my guess) but correct expression that will do the job - until then I'm going with the simple alternative.

Comment: @CompuChip let the OP decide his question is clear he want a regex  if the answer was done in a way that he point out why he should not use RegEx I would upvote to

Answer (score 2):

It is not that difficult in regex:

- If the complete string has to match just use:

  ```
  ^(?=.{8}$)\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*$
  ```

  [See it here on regexr](http://regexr.com?3804r).
- If this is a word in a larger text use:

  ```
  \b(?=[a-z0-9]{8}\b)\d*[a-z]\d*\b
  ```

  [See it here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3805a)

`\d*[a-z]\d*` matches any amount of digits, followed by one letter, then again any amount of digits.

`(?=[a-z0-9]{8}` is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), this ensures the length of 8 in total.

Important here is the use of [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) or [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to avoid partial wrong matches.

If you really want to match **any** letter then use the [Unicode property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) `\p{L}` instead of the character class:

```
^(?=.{8}$)\d*\p{L}\d*$
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this if you want one letter and 7 digit

```
 "[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{7}[A-Za-z]{1}|[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{6}[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}"
```

and here a code snippet how you can iterate through your result

```
 string st = "1111111q 2222222q 111e1111 11e11111";
            string pattS = @"[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{7}[A-Za-z]{1}|[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{6}[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattS);
           var res = regex.Matches(st);
            foreach (var re in res)
            {

            }
```

check [here](http://rubular.com/r/5WanrWg3jp) on rubular it covers all examples you provide

Comment: The problem with this is that the letter must be either at the beginning or at then end. There are other patterns as well, such as 1s11111, 11s1111, etc. This would mean that you could have a large amount of patterns, one for each possible position of the letter in particular.

Comment: These two regular expressions do not match the 3rd and 4th example provided by the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

This will match what you want:

`(\d{1}\w\d{6}|\d{2}\w\d{5}|\d{3}\w\d{4}|\d{4}\w\d{3}|\d{5}\w\d{2}|\d{6}\w\d{1}|\d{7}\w)`

I generated it like this, in powershell:

```
$n = 6;
for ($i = 1; $i -le 6; $i++) {
    write-host "\d{"$i"}\w\d{"$n"}"
    $n--
}
```

Comment: Except it will also match `1111d33333`, and although OP has not specified whether that should match his examples suggest not.

Comment: I agree, it will match that. Regex is just that thing, lack of specificity and it's not going to be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your example will only work when the character is the first character in the string.

The problem you've got is that you need a total of 7 digits, and absolutely only one character potentially within those 7 digits. This is not something that's possible with regular expressions as defined in theory, because you have to have a link between the two groups of digits to see how many are in the other group and regexes can't carry that kind of context around with them.

I was wondering if it was possible using a lookahead assertion to ensure there's only one letter, but the best I can do is ensuring there's no instance of two letters in a row, which doesn't cover all possible invalid cases. Thus I think you're going to have to find another method, as npinti suggested. So something like:

```
public static bool Match(string s) {
  return (s.Length == 8) &&
         (s.Where(Char.IsDigit).Count() == 7) &&
         (s.Where(Char.IsLetter).Count() == 1);
}
```

But I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 0):

With Regex, you can do it in two steps. First you can remove the character, in whatever position it is:

```
string input = "111a1111";  
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]");
string output=rgx.Replace(input,"",1); // remove only one character
                                       // output = "1111111"
```

then you can match with `[0-9]{7}` (if you don't want all digits to be the same)
or with `^(\d)\1{6}$` (if you want 7 occurrences of the same digit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
^([0-9])(?:\1|[a-z](?!.*[a-z])){7}|[a-z]([0-9])\2{6}$
```